# In Unity for Android, how do I create touchable buttons?

Tags: unity, android, touch, controllers

I'm making a test game for Android in Unity 5, and I want to add left-right control buttons like the circles below, to move an object left or right.

[image: a left and right button under a simple game view]
<sub>(source: [raywenderlich.com](https://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/part2_8b_joysticks_gameview.png))</sub>

How can I do this?

Sorry if this question is basic. I'm new to Unity and I don't understand the methods of existing tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Since Android devices don't have left/right buttons (well, a long time ago they used to, and if you use bluetooth keyboard/gamepads they will), what you want is **onscreen buttons**. If you search for that then you will find plenty of answers and tutorials.

The easiest method is to use the built-in [`GUI.Button`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html) class. There are many other ways to do it, such as detecting touch events and checking if they intersect some part of the screen.

Comment: So I need to add any object and write a script for OnTouch or OnClick on the object ?